# How to bevel this simple edge?

Tags: bevel

I need to bevel the edge inside the red square to make it round maintaining the top edge flat. It's very simple geometry but I don't get it. Can someone help me with this?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After beveling (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) select the top vertex of the n-gon, enable the *snapping tool (Vertex)* and snap it verticaly to create a straight line.
[image]

Clean up the mesh a bit using *dissolve* option and remesh it. Note, that the topology pictured below is just an example. You have to think how to arrange it to make the *subsurf modifier* work properly.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

- In *Edit Mode*, first select the two vertices on each side of this edge
- Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> --> Assign to new group
- In the *modifiers* tab, add *Bevel* modifier
- Choose *Limit method* to be *vertex group*
- Select the vertex group
- The edge should be beveled

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, Faceb but that makes messy geometry.

I was trying something else and I think I found the solution.

I merged all the flat faces I had and the the bevel works correctly. I get some tris thought that I don't know if I could solve it in any other way...

[image]